# Self Hosted website gets "request timed out" for ONLY one person

Tags: web, connection, self-hosting, synology

I have several self hosted webpages.
And one of them seems to have stopped working for a single person.
He is able to successfully connect and use one of the two webpages and not the other. Both of these webpages are hosted by the same (Synology NAS) device in my home. And the other webpage was also working for him about one month ago. Other people seems to have no issues connecting to either webpage (tested several places and countries).

Here is what we have tried so far:

- Using different web browsers
- Using different devices
- Using different routing (aka. VPN)
- Using different internets (aka. mobile data plan)
- Reset his router/modem

Any ideas as to what might be wrong would be appriciated.

Comment: What is my personal hypothesis as of right now, is that our ISP is routing our traffic locally through the national stations as a shortcut. Since can see that the source and destination IP both reside within this country.

And for some reason, a critical station between us two specifically is out of order since the rain flood about a month ago. This could explain the LAN situation, but I don't think the mobile network is even connected to regular LAN base stations at all, that is all satelite, is it not? (If so, mobile network should have worked for us)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We eventually discovered that **we were able to connect if we specified the default https port at the end of the url**. Which was really strange. That should by no means be required unless you are using a non-standard port.

Anyways, I don't know what causes this issue on multiple devices. But apparently it works again with the normal url as well after running the following command.

```
ipfonfig /flushdns
```